# Using count($array) to retrieve only matching $key

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, loops

I am running a loop of an `$array` where I am only including results that have a matching user role (from Wordpress users).

I have the loop:

```
// custom function that returns the user's role (administrator, reader, etc)
$userRole = get_current_user_role();

foreach( $location_array as $key => $location ) {
    if( in_array( $userRole, $location['c'] ) ) {
        // do the things

        echo '<div style="width: calc( 100vw / ' . count($array) . ');">';
            echo $location['a'];
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

With the `$array` composing of:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [a] => Location 1
        [b] => loc04
        [c] => Array ( [administrator] => administrator )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [a] => Location 2
        [b] => loc23
        [c] => Array ( [administrator] => administrator, [publisher] => publisher )
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [a] => Location 3
        [b] => loc12
        [c] => Array ( [publisher] => publisher, [viewer] => viewer )
    )
)
```

However, when I try to get the count of the `$array`, it is returning the number of all the `$key`, and I dont know how to narrow it down to just the ones from the `in_array( $userRole, $location['c']`

I have tried putting the `in_array( $userRole, $location['c']` from the loop into a variable, and then outputting that but I wasnt having any success with it other than returning the value of 1, but there being two matches for administrator

Comment: _"when I try to get the count of the `$array`"_ - Where are you doing that?  Please show us _all_ the relevant code, what all the variables contains and what the result should be and what you're currently getting.

Comment: You realize that we have _no clue_ what `$array` contains, right?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson added the count use

Comment: You added the code where you have `count($array)`, but since that's the _only_ reference of that variable in your code, we have no idea what it contains, how it's defined and populated or what `count($array)` should return.

Comment: You need to filter `$array` first according your role and then you can use `count` and echo what ever you want. You cannot just start echo before the loop if you want to filter some of the element out. I am assuming `$location_array` and `$array` are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the count on the array on-going. You need to **filter it first**!

You can use [array-filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) as:

```
$arr = [["b" => "loc04", "c" => ["administrator" => "administrator"]]];
$arr[] = ["b" => "loc23", "c" => ["administrator" => "administrator", "publisher" => "publisher"]];
$arr[] = ["b" => "loc12", "c" => ["publisher" => "publisher", "viewer" => "viewer"]];
$role = "administrator";
$a = array_filter($arr, function ($e) use ($role) {return in_array($role, $e["c"]);});
```

Now `$a` will contain the 2 element.

If the key as the same as the value you better use `isset` (faster - O(1) instead O(n)) as:

```
$a = array_filter($arr, function ($e) use ($role) {return isset($e["c"][$role]);});
```

Then you can just loop over `$a` and do:

```
foreach($a as $location) {
    echo '<div style="width: calc( 100vw / ' . count($a) . ');">';
    echo $location['a'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/WpQQt)